# Tangentialcone on a nonconvex set

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a question regarding the notion of the tangentialcone used in nonlinear optimization.

Say we have a nonconvex admissible set $X$:

$X :=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^2|x_1\geq0,x_2\geq0,x_1x_2\leq0\rbrace$

The tangentialcone at $(0,0)$ is then the whole set $X$ as far as I can understand from the definition, but $X$ is not a cone?

Comment: No X is just the two axis' bounding the 1. quadrant

Comment: $X$ is a cone, just not convex...

Comment: But how does it fullfill the 2. property of a cone, that if you add two random elements in the cone you get a third element which is also in the cone?

Comment: that is a part of the definition of a **convex** cone.

Comment: That explains a thing or two. Thanks!